# How to prove Hilbert-style $(\Box(p\rightarrow q)\wedge\Diamond(p\wedge r))\rightarrow\Diamond(q\wedge r)$ in **K**?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Edit: I figured out how to solve it using the theorem K9: $\Box(p\vee q)\rightarrow\Box p\vee\Diamond q$ on p. 36 and then manipulating it using the rules of propositional logic. If you have any alternative suggestions, feel free to respond.

I am trying to solve (c) of Exercise 2.1 (p. 48) in Hughes and Cresswell's *New Introduction to Modal Logic*. Here is what I attempted (in $\LaTeX$ notation):

1. $\Box(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow\Box((p\rightarrow r)\rightarrow(p\rightarrow(q\wedge r)))$ (valid in **K**)
2. $\Box(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(\Diamond(p\rightarrow r)\rightarrow\Diamond(p\rightarrow(q\wedge r)))$
3. $\neg\Box(p\rightarrow q)\vee(\Diamond(p\rightarrow r)\rightarrow\Diamond(p\rightarrow(q\wedge r)))$
4. $\neg(\Box(p\rightarrow q)\wedge\Diamond(\neg p\vee r))\vee\Diamond(\neg p\vee(q\wedge r))$
5. $\ldots$
6. $\ldots$
7. $\ldots$
8. $(\Box(p\rightarrow q)\wedge\Diamond\neg(p\wedge\neg r))\rightarrow\Diamond(\neg(p\wedge\neg(q\wedge r)))$

Comment: Is your carrot symbol ^ supposed to be $\wedge$?

Comment: @MatthewH. Yes, it stands for conjunction.

Comment: @Matthew H. I don't think the *caret* symbol is very similar to this vegetable....

Comment: @Gonçalo The meanings differ depending on what intensional system you're operating in. In alethic logic, box means "it is necessary that" and diamond means "it is possible that". But in deontic logic, for instance, box stands for "it is obligatory that" while diamond stands for "it is permissible that".

Answer (score 1):

I’ll set you up with the “boxed” instance of the propositional theorem you’ll want to use to prove this. You’ll also have to use the equivalence

$(p \to (q \to r)) \leftrightarrow ((p \land q) \to r)$.

Here’s how I would get started:

1. $\Box ((p \to q) \to ((p \land r) \to (q \land r)))$

Comment: Thanks, but since you say "also have to use", you don't need to use them if you use K9 but simply substitute and use rules of PL to reach the result, like I stated at the beginning of my post.

Comment: I also realized that 1 is an instance of using the weakening rule. I have not in general seen structural weakening stated as a derivation rule in modal logic, nor should it be derivable. That is not to say, of course, that your method won't work.

Comment: It’s just an instance of a propositional tautology.